# How to Tokenize A Text By Regular Expression In Python

Tags: python, tokenize, corpus, linguistics

Is there any way to clean a text from whitespaces and dots, commas without NLTK, but especially by regular expressions?

Comment: Do you simply want to remove *all* spaces, dots and commas etc, without any other constraint? Use `replace`, or, even better, the `translate` method.

Comment: I also want to create a list.

Comment: a list of what? the characters remaining after the removal?

Comment: This is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It is not a how-to-program site, nor is it a debug-code-for-free site. Please read the documenattion about ``re`` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your question you can try this code

```
import re

text = "Split.this,text in seven.separate,words"

myexp=re.compile(r'[\s.,]')

print myexp.split(text)
```

that gives you this output

```
['Split', 'this', 'text', 'in', 'seven', 'separate', 'words']
```